# Is there a time series ML model (like TimesFormer) which extracts features from 4 channel input images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, time-series, feature-extraction

Regular TimesFormer takes 3 channel input images, while I have 4 channel images (RGBD). I am struggling to find a TimesFormer (or a model similar to TimesFormer) that takes 4 channel input images and extract features from them.

Does anybody know such a model? Preferably, I would like to find pretrained model with weights.

**MORE CONTEXT:**

**I am working with **RGBD video frames** and have multiclass classification problem at the end.** My videos are fairly large, between 2 to 4 minutes so classical time-series models doesn't work for me. So my inputs are RGBD frames/images from the video and at the end I would like to get class prediction.

**My idea was to divide the problem into 2 stages:**

1. Extract features from video into smaller dimension with TimesFormer-like model. Result: I would get a new data representation (dataset).
2. Train clasification ML network with new data to get a class prediction.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 2023, I don't think there's any readily available TimeSformer model/code that  works on RGBD 4 channel image.

Alternatively, If you are looking for Vision Transformers that can work with `depth` as well (`RGBD` data), you have the entire list with state-of-the-art approaches and corresponding code (wherever available) [here](https://github.com/cmhungsteve/Awesome-Transformer-Attention#depth-estimation).

One of the good approach to start with is [DepthFormer: Exploiting Long-Range Correlation and Local Information for Accurate Monocular Depth Estimation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.14211.pdf). You can find the pre-trained models with this approach [here](https://github.com/zhyever/Monocular-Depth-Estimation-Toolbox/blob/main/docs/model_zoo.md).

If you're looking for 3D CNN based object detectors that can work on RGBD data: [RGB-D Salient Object Detection via 3D Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.05585.pdf) is one of the good ones to start with. Code and pre-trained models can be found [here](https://github.com/QianChen98/RD3D#inference).

Since I don't fully understand your problem statement or exact requirement I'm proposed few things that I thought could be helpful.

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, I edited the post with additional context. Do you have any other suggestions? 
Thank you.